# Pygame: How to iterate through numbers and check for key presses on each number using pygame.key.get_pressed?

Tags: python, pygame

Currently I have the below set-up. Doing so for 9 more numbers is a bit messy. Is there a way to have a code resembling the "Target" below?

Current:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_1]:
    print("1")
# more if statements
```

Target:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
for value in values:
    if keys[some_pygame_function(value)]:
        print(str(value))
```

An alternative I found so far is by using events from `pygame.event.get()` instead. However, I prefer it in `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

Answer (score 2):

What you can actually do is the following:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

for value in values:
    if keys[ord(str(value))]:
        print(value)
```

In the array that `pygame.key.get_pressed()` returns, the values for the keys that are pressed are set to `True`. The indexes of the keys are similar to the `ord()` of that character. `ord()` however does expect a string.

Similarly, using `pygame.key.get()`, you can also achieve the same:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print(event.key) 
        print(chr(event.key)) # converts it back to a character
```

Here, `event.key` is the `ord()` of the character. To convert that back, you perform `chr()` on said key. So, pressing `1` for instance, yields '49' (the ord) and `1` as character. I just wanted to add this since, for this, you do not need to define all values you iterate over, and skips the iteration part and thus is more efficient.

Comment: Nice! It works. Also, do you know the ord difference between pygame.K_KP1 and pygame.K_1?

Comment: `K_KPx` are the numpad numbers, while `K_x` are the keyboard numbers

Comment: Yeah, nvm. I found it by testing. For those looking, K_KPx - K_x = 1073741864.